# How do I POST a file to my backend, using Thymeleaf with Spring's @ModelAttribute?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Using `@ModelAttribute` I am able to post form-data to my backend without issue, however when I try to include a multipart file the server returns a 500 error. There are no console warnings or stack traces thrown, and the POST request endpoint is never hit according to my debugger.

I've tried working backwards, and replacing the `MultiPartFile` with just a `String` and changing the file attribute in the HTML to text, and it works just find sending `String`s and `int`s to the back end, but when I add the file type back in and switch the model to `MultipartFile`, it breaks...

The html form fragment, the submit button triggers the POST request to /new:

```html
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/release/new}" class="mx-auto w-50" th:object="${package}">
        <th:block th:include="fragment/error-message.html"></th:block>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Release Package Information</legend>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                    <label>Release Package ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the release package ID" th:field="*{releasePackageId}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
                    <label>Nomenclature</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the part nomenclature" th:field="*{nomenclature}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
                    <label>File</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Select the part to upload" th:field="*{file}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <a th:href="@{/release}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100">
                    Back
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success w-100">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And here are the controller endpoints for /release/new:

```java
    @GetMapping("/new")
    public ModelAndView showCreateReleasePackageForm()
    {
        return new ModelAndView("new-release").addObject("package", new CreateReleasePackageDTO());
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/new")
    public String createReleasePackage(@ModelAttribute("package") CreateReleasePackageDTO releasePackageDTO, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attributes)
    {
        if (result.hasErrors())
        {
            return "new-release";
        }
        String response = "a response";
        System.out.println(releasePackageDTO.getReleasePackageId() + releasePackageDTO.getNomenclature() + releasePackageDTO.getFile());
        // TODO: Exception handling
        //  try
        //  {
        //      response = this.fileService.save(ReleasePackageMapper.toEntity(releasePackageDTO));
        //  } catch (JsonProcessingException e)
        //  {
        //      response = e.getMessage();
        //      e.printStackTrace();
        //  }
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("message", response);
        return "redirect:/release";
    }
```

Here is the DTO, the model object I am calling "package":

```java
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class CreateReleasePackageDTO
    {
        @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.releasePackageId}")
        private int releasePackageId;
    
        @NotEmpty(message = "{NotEmpty.nomenclature}")
        private String nomenclature;
    
        @NotEmpty(message = "{NotEmpty.multipartFile}")
        private MultipartFile file;
    }
```

Comment: uploading a file is easy as long as you stick to the well-known recipes. Don't wrap a file inside a class (CreateReleasePackageDTO). Instead have a MutipartFile as an argument in your controller method.